# Python random module - randint error unsure what the error is

Tags: python

I have this error `module random has no attribute randint` and I'm not sure why. I have no files containing the word random which is whats confusing me why it is issuing the error.
The code is below:

```
import random

#generate a random integer between a and b 
randInt = random.rantint(1,500) 
print("randInt: ", randInt) 

#generate random int from range
randrange = random.randrange(0,500,5)
print("randRange: ", randrange)
```

If someone could give me any advice that would be sick cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `rantint` instead of `randint` on line 3
This will work:

```py
import random

#generate a random integer between a and b 
randInt = random.randint(1,500) # Here
print("randInt: ", randInt) 

#generate random int from range
randrange = random.randrange(0,500,5)
print("randRange: ", randrange)
```

Comment: Ah! you are correct thank you very much! It's been a long day lol

Comment: @factive, if you find it correct, mark this question as correct so others notice this :)